# Error LNK2028: unresolved token

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Hi I have seen this type of question have been asked before but none of them worked for me. Thats why I am asking again.

I have written a code using opencv 2.4 and I have added all the files needed by the code. but still I am getting this error.

```
Error   1   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000C) "extern "C" unsigned long __stdcall ibwrt(int,void const *,unsigned int)" (?ibwrt@@$$J212YGKHPBXI@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl WriteData(void const *,unsigned int)" (?WriteData@@$$FYAHPBXI@Z)    D:\F1Nh-TESTER-2014-08-04\PUMA_LED_TESTER\PUMA_LED_TESTER\ni_gpib.obj   PUMA_LED_TESTER
```

I tried solving this by adding the header file related to this function but nothing worked. Please help me resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

That's a linker error and says that it is missing the **implementation** of function *ibwrt*.

Adding header files does not help, you need to find either the library that implements it or the .c/.cpp file with its definition

Comment: The .cpp file containing its definition is already added to the solution @marom